# Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined - InnerHTML <script> tag with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, innerhtml

I have a component in Angular, the content of which is supplied by a backend that provides HTML code. I add it to the component as inner HTML. There is a  and a  tag in the HTML supplied. However, while I think the styles are being honoured, I am unable to call the function in the script tag.

The `<script>` tag:

```js
  function ToggleDisplayMode(node) 
    {
        var tableHeader = document.getElementById(node);
        if (null != tableHeader)
        {
            var row = tableHeader.nextSibling;
            while (row != null)
            {
                if ( row.style.display != "none" ) {
                    row.style.display = "none";
                }
                else {
                    row.style.display = "";
                }
                row = row.nextSibling;
            }
        }
    }
```

How I am calling this function:

```
<a onclick="ToggleDisplayMode(<args>)"><u>show/hide</u></a>
```

The click doesn't work and I get the following output in the console:

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: ToggleDisplayMode is not defined
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (<args>)
```

The function is clearly defined, so I do not understand what I am doing wrong here.

I have checked several posts on the issue, but they're JQuery based. Is this an issue with how Angular might treat inner HTML?

**EDIT:**
The click needs to be handled by JavaScript and not Angular (because of the pecularities of this system), so `ngClick` or `(click)` will not work.

**EDIT 2:**
Apparently, `<script>` tags in `innerHtml` don't get executed according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml). Will have to find another way to do this then.

Comment: which version of angular are you using?  and what is `<args>` here?

Comment: It is a design quirk, but this HTML is supplied by an SDK we have and the angular app was built on top of it later. The same HTML is used in a number of other client interfaces, so I cannot make changes there. So I cannot use `ngClick`

Comment: Angular 4 at the moment, and the <args> are basically the node ID in the HTML. See `var tableHeader = document.getElementById(node);` in the second line of the function.

Comment: If you open up the console and type `ToggleDisplayMode` does it return anything? If not then `ToggleDisplayMode` is not on the global scope

Comment: sounds like your function is not in global scope.

Comment: @epascarello the structure is something like `<div><script><func></script><all calls to that function></div>`

Comment: in which file you have added `<script>` tag. try adding it in `src/index.html` within `<head>` tag.

Comment: I tried to put the script on top of my HTML file, still not working. Any pointers on how to make it global?

Comment: It won't be right to put it in index.html in my opinion. The function is used only in a specific place.

Answer (score 0):

Angular looks for code in the component's typescript file, so I think you'd need to put the code there. You can create a service to get the code from the backend, then call the service from your typescript file and use a (click) event to call the typescript code.

Comment: I'm not using `ngClick` but simple JavaScript `onclick` so it shouldn't be Angular handling the clicks here.

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530261/javascript-button-onclick-not-working

Comment: cannot do that because the IDs are dynamic and multiple places use the same function

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code like this:

```
<a (click)="ToggleDisplayMode()"><u>show/hide</u></a>
```

Notice that instead of `onclick`, you have to use `(click)`

Comment: That is an Angular solution - changes at that level will not be possible as this HTML is returned by an SDK and the same response is used in other, non-Angular interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Angular version 9.1.9
typescript 3.8.3

You can add a js file under assets folder

src/assets/js/child2.js

> ```
> function javaChangeCreatedBy() {
>     alert('Set 2 clicked');
>
>     var i_createdby = document.getElementById('inputcreatedbyid')
>     var i_value = document.getElementById('inputcreatedbyid').value;
> }
> ```

Following html code shows the both approach one for angular click and one for html onclick.

src/app/first-component/first-component.component.html

```
<p>
    Enter Created by:<input id='inputcreatedbyid' type="text" placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]=inputcreatedby>
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" (click)="ChangeCreatedBy(inputcreatedby)">Set</button> 
    &nbsp;
    <button type="button" onclick="javaChangeCreatedBy()">Set 2</button>
</p>
```

src/app/first-component/first-component.component.ts

```
 export class FirstComponentComponent implements OnInit {
      ..
      createdby = 'My name';
      inputcreatedby='';

      ChangeCreatedBy(inputcreatedby:string){
           // var inputvalue = document.getElementById("inputcreatedby").value;
           this.createdby = inputcreatedby;
      }
 }
```

And finally add the script file into angular.json file

```
 {
    "projects": {
       "architect": {
           "build": {
              ..
              "options": {
                 ..
                 "scripts": [
                    "src/assets/js/child2.js"
                 ]
              }
```

However angular doesn't support passing type script parameter to java function.