# Why the onclick not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to use `onclick` to call a `function` when user click the button, which seems not working.

For example:

```js
function click(){
   console.log('you click it!')
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='submitbutton' value = 'Submit' onclick= 'click(); console.log("you used it in HTML")'>
```

if i remove the `console.log` in `onclick`, no message will be `console`.

```js
function click(){
   console.log('you click it!')
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='submitbutton' value = 'Submit' onclick= "click();">
```

The button will `console` the message `you used it in HTML` which I directly write inside the `onclick`, but will fail to execute the function `click()` I assign to it.

I think it is not the problem of `input[type='button']` since we could use `onclick` in `input[type='button']`. For [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_button).

Could anyone explain me what makes the code doesn't work? I know the solution for this is  probably to use `addEventListener`, but **why doesn't this work?**

Possible duplicate of [JavaScript button onclick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530261/javascript-button-onclick-not-working), but this question only suggests the solution not explaining the reason.

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: change your function name, because ```click``` is from ```HTMLElement.prototype.click```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline handlers have a very, very peculiar scope chain - and for that reason (among others), should not be used, because their behavior can be unintuitive.

Here, `click` refers to the `.click` on HTMLElement's prototype:

```html
<input type='button' id='submitbutton' value = 'Submit' onclick= 'console.log(click === HTMLElement.prototype.click)'>
```

So your `function click` and your inline `click()` are referencing different things. When you click:

- The inline handler will run `HTMLElement.prototype.click` on the button, resulting in a second event to  be dispatched synchronously, which will once again trigger that same handler. It won't enter an infinite loop though, because `.click()` has a [special flag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#click-in-progress-flag) to prevent exactly that to happen. Then, `you used it in HTML` gets logged.
- Once this second *synthetic* event has been handled, `you used it in HTML` will be logged again, from the inline handler.

Another way to look at it:

- Button click

  - Inline handler invoked due to click

    - Inline handler invoked again due to `.click()` in inline handler

      - Inline handler *not* invoked again (because the *click in progress flag* is raised)
      - Log occurs
    - Log occurs
- Call stack is now empty

Use a different name for the function - or, even better, avoid the inline handlers entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the long detailed answer! So the JS recognize the `click()` as `HTMLElement.click()`, but a little stupid question. I doesn't assign the element (e.g. input) to `HTMLElement.click()`, how could I being work?

Comment: Invoking `HTMLElement.prototype.click` on an element will result in that element's `onclick` handlers being run, including inline handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

**Hi** The error is this: `click()` is a javascript function, change the name to other. More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

```js
function clicka(){
   console.log('you click it!')
}
```

```html
<input 
type='button' 
id='submitbutton' 
value='Submit' 
onclick='clicka();console.log("you used it in HTML")'>
```